# Conditional loop with running sum is skipping values

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I have created this code with the purpose of:

**First Loop:**

- Loop through cells in `column O` to find anything that starts with `DAAP`.
- If Cell 5 columns left of `DAAP` is empty then add the cell 1 column to the right (which is a number) to `Total`. Then rename the cell to `GAAF`
- If Cell 5 columns left is not empty then just rename the cell to `GAAF`

**Second Loop:**

- Find all `GAAF` cells in `column O` and then change the cell 1 column to the right to `Total`

Here is the code I have, it runs with no errors but just does nothing. I'm assuming something is syntax'ed wrong so it's looking in the wrong place but I can't find it! Any help is greatly appreciated :)

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim lstRow As Long
Dim AUMCell As Range
Dim Total As Long

lstRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp).Row

Set rng = Range("O2", Cells(lstRow, "O"))

Total = 0

For Each AUMCell In rng
    If AUMCell.value = "DAAP" & "*" And AUMCell.Offset(0, -5).value = "" Then
        Total = Total + AUMCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        AUMCell.value = "GAAF"
    ElseIf AUMCell.value = "DAAP" & "*" And AUMCell.Offset(0, -5).value <> "" Then
        AUMCell.value = "GAAF"
    End If
Next AUMCell

For Each AUMCell In rng
    If AUMCell.Value = "GAAF" Then
        AUMCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Total
    End If
Next AUMCell
```

Comment: Did you run it on the desired sheet? Because you didn't qualify your ranges.

Comment: I did! In my full macro I have a Sheets("").activate line just before it. Good thought though :)

Comment: It has to do with If `AUMCell.value = "DAAP" & "*"` use `INSTR(AUMCell.value ,"DAAP")>0` instead.  Or replace the `=` with `Like` it may work also.

Comment: gimme 2 secs to try this, will report back soon!

Comment: You should avoid code that relies on `Select` and `Activate`, and that uses implicit references to the active sheet / workbook. If your worksheet is always going to be the same, use its global identifier instead - e.g. `Worksheets("Sheet1")` usually has a `Sheet1` object reference that's right there waiting to be used.

Comment: Scott your comment has solved the problem!!!! Thank you so much, Could I ask why the original method with Wildcards was not working?

Comment: When using the `=` it is looking for an exact.  So it was looking for `DAAP*` not `DAAP` and what ever comes after it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the code is longer the execution of `Find` will be much quicker than a loop through each cell.

```
    Sub Recut()
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim rng3 As Range

    Dim aCell As Range
    Dim bCell As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim SearchString As String


    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set rng1 = ws.Range("O:O")

    SearchString = "DAAP"

    Set aCell = rng1.Find(SearchString, , xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, xlNext)

    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        Set bCell = aCell
        If Left$(aCell.Value, 4) = SearchString Then Set rng2 = aCell
        Do
            Set aCell = rng1.FindNext(After:=aCell)
             If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                If aCell.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do
                 If Left$(aCell.Value, 4) = SearchString Then
                    If Not rng2 Is Nothing Then
                        Set rng2 = Union(rng2, aCell)
                    Else
                        Set rng2 = aCell
                    End If
                 End If
            Else
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
    Else
        MsgBox SearchString & " not Found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If rng2 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    For Each rng3 In rng2
      If Len(rng3.Offset(0, -5)) = 0 Then Total = Total + rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value
      rng3.Value = "GAFF"
    Next

    MsgBox Total

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this code

```
For Each AUMCell In rng
    If AUMCell.value = "DAAP" & "*" And AUMCell.Offset(0, -5).value = "" Then
        Total = Total + AUMCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        AUMCell.value = "GAAF"
    ElseIf AUMCell.value = "DAAP" & "*" And AUMCell.Offset(0, -5).value <> "" Then
        AUMCell.value = "GAAF"
    End If 
Next AUMCell
```

by this code

```
For Each AUMCell In rng
    If AUMCell.value like "DAAP*" Then 
        If AUMCell.Offset(0, -5).value = "" Then
            Total = Total + AUMCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        End If        
        AUMCell.value = "GAAF"
    End If
Next AUMCell
```

P.S.: Sorry my english